# Incorporate tuples of information in JSON format stored in array in postresql

Tags: postgresql

I have the following postgresql function that allows me to obtain a table with information from two parameters that are indicated. However, now I want to modify this code so that it allows me to incorporate each tuple of information in JSON format and store all of them in an array and I can not find a way to do it successfully. Thank you in advance for your interest and help.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name ( date DATE, name text)
RETURNS json language plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN 
    PERFORM json_agg(row_to_json(row(name, age, address, locality, ID)))
    FROM people, addresses
    RETURN;
END;
$$
```

Comment: Not clear what you want and how your json object should look like, so I'll just give you the link to the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html And I can't imagine you're still using version 9.1 or 9.2 please remove these tags. Or migrate to a recent version.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Hi Frank! Well I think finally should look something like this ][{'name': Susan, 'age':19, 'address': X, 'Locality':Y, 'ID': Z}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested as you did not supply example data.

Still here is a potential solution:

```
SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(row(name, age, address, locality, ID)))
            FROM people, addresses;
```

If you want `jsonb` just replace `json` in above with `jsonb`.

**UPDATE** for change in requirements:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name ( date DATE, name text)
RETURNS json language plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
    _json_var json;
BEGIN 
    SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(row(name, age, address, locality, ID)))
    FROM people, addresses INTO _json_var;
    RETURN _json_var;
END;
$$
```

If you are not going to return a query you will need to return the results of the query into some variable or variables and return them. See [RETURN INTO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW).

Comment: Thank you @Adrian Klaver, your idea seems to work, however, I get this error: ERROR: execution reached the end of the function without encountering RETURN. Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Looking back your function in the question , you need a `RETURN;` just before the `END;`. See here [RETURN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) for more information.

Comment: Yes I have tried but it still does not work.... In fact I have made other changes (the ones I edited as you will see above) however I don't know why it keeps crashing.

Comment: See UPDATE to answer. Also remember in `plpgsql` all statements need to end with a `;`.

Comment: Great contribution. Works perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a json array of json objects whose key/value pairs correspond to the selected columns, then you can try this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name ( date DATE, name text)
RETURNS jsonb language sql AS
$$
BEGIN
     SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('name', name, 'age', age, 'address', address, 'locality', locality, 'ID', ID))
       FROM people, addresses
END;
$$
```

but I don't really understand why you have input parameters (date DATE, name text) that you don't use in your function ?